# How can I check it?

Tags: real-analysis

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2^{n}\pi x)}{n\cdot2^{n}}, $$

Is $f$ an absolutely continuous function? If yes how can I show it? If not how about on total variation of $f$ ?

Comment: Start with the definition of absolute continuity.

Comment: @shade4159 I'd add that the most useful definition seems to be the one concerning the fundamental theorem of Lebesgue integral calculus, but I doubt many people learn that as the 'definition' of the term (I don't even feel certain most only encounter absolute continuity after they've learned Lebesgue integration).

Comment: @JonathanY. Good points!